# How can I use glut with a Windows cross-compiler on Linux?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, undefined-reference

I have a the mingw32 cross compiler for Linux which compiles windows binaries on linux. everything worked out pretty fine until I needed to install glut... I installed fine in linux but whenever I try to compile the same program on windows I can boil it down to:

> /tmp/ccQhHDhy.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `__imp__glClear'
>   /tmp/ccQhHDhy.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to`_*imp*_glBegin'
>   /tmp/ccQhHDhy.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `__imp__glVertex3f'
>   /tmp/ccQhHDhy.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to`_*imp*_glVertex3f'
>   /tmp/ccQhHDhy.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `__imp__glVertex3f'
>   /tmp/ccQhHDhy.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to`_*imp*_glEnd'

by linking with the dll directly

after getting these linker errors I tried linking opengl32 gdi32 winmm the glut lib file and glu32

but still the same this

heres the source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
using namespace std;
void render(void);
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(-1,-1);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("My First Glut Application");
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void render(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, .5, 0.0);
    glEnd();


}
```

Comment: In your case it's not so much the source code we need to see, but the compiler/linker calls.

Answer (score 2):

Your program can be compiled without errors in Windows. The reason why there are linking errors are probably that you do not use the correct makefile. However, there are some errors in your code. You can make the following change:

- add `glutSwapBuffers()` at the end of the `render` function.

Then use the makefile for mingw:

`g++ -o prog -c prog.cpp -lopengl32 -lfreeglut -lglu32`

Comment: As noted, you *must* link to the libraries, not the dll. Dll is a binary that typically contains little metadata, headers and libs provide the bindings necessary to use the dll (same concept as shared objects).

Comment: There is no semantical difference between `render` and `&render`, they both yield the same result. It's not a error to write `glutDisplayFunc(render)`.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually tried freeglut and after failing cross compiling it. I got precompiled windows binaries and after changing
`#include <GL/glut.h>`
to
`#include <GL/freeglut.h>`

and linking with freeglut32 it worked
and thanks sean for pointing out those errors

Comment: If you use freeglut, it is no need to make this change. The freeglut packpage includes a header named by "glut.h",  this header will call freeglut_std.h. This setting makes sure the code cross-platform , that is to say, it is no need to change your code, and only change the makefile or compiling and linking commands